# Need to modify Dictionary and its element based on conditions in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Input :

```
dict1 = {'Category': ['item1','item2','item3','item4'],
 'Freq': [71984.0, 8129.0, 3140.0, 0.0]}
```

Output :

```
dict2 = {'Category': ['item1','item2','item3'],
 'Freq': [71984.0, 8129.0, 3140.0]}
```

Task to do:

Make a new Dictionary without all 0.0 Freq values and respective item from Category.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] of your attempt before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more elegant way to solve this, but this definitely does the trick:

```
dict1 = {'Category': ['item1','item2','item3','item4'],
 'Freq': [71984.0, 8129.0, 3140.0, 0.0]}

# create an empty list to save indices that you want to delete from both lists
del_ind = []

# iterate over the list of Frequencies
for x in dict1['Freq']:
  # if the value euquals 0.0, append the index of this value to your list
  if x == 0.0:
    ind = dict1['Freq'].index(x)
    del_ind.append(ind)

# then iterate over the list of indices you want to delete and use the pop method to delete those entries from both of your lists
for x in del_ind:
  dict1['Category'].pop(x)
  dict1['Freq'].pop(x)

print(dict1)
```

outputs:

```
{'Category': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], 'Freq': [71984.0, 8129.0, 3140.0]}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach using `zip`

**Ex:**

```
dict1 = {'Category': ['item1','item2','item3','item4'],'Freq': [71984.0, 8129.0, 3140.0, 0.0]}
Category, Freq = zip(*[(m,n) for m,n in zip(*dict1.values()) if n])
result = {"Category":Category, "Freq":Freq}

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Category': ('item1', 'item2', 'item3'), 'Freq': (71984.0, 8129.0, 3140.0)}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with using `pandas`, you can do the following:

First create a pandas DataFrame by passing `dict1` into the DataFrame constructor:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
print(df)
#  Category     Freq
#0    item1  71984.0
#1    item2   8129.0
#2    item3   3140.0
#3    item4      0.0
```

Now keep only the rows where `Freq!=0`:

```
print(df[df['Freq']!=0])
#  Category     Freq
#0    item1  71984.0
#1    item2   8129.0
#2    item3   3140.0
```

To get it back into a dictionary:

```
dict2 = df[df['Freq']!=0].to_dict(orient='list')
print(dict2)
#{'Category': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], 'Freq': [71984.0, 8129.0, 3140.0]}
```

The advantage of using this method is that it's easy to apply to more than just 2 lists.

Answer (score 2):

The below code will do the trick.

```
dict1 = {'Category': ['item1','item2','item3','item4'],
 'Freq': [71984.0, 8129.0, 3140.0, 0.0]}

zipped = zip(*dict1.values())
filtered = filter(lambda x : x[1] != 0.0, zipped)
result = map(list, zip(*filtered))
print {
    'Category': result[0],
    'Freq': result[1]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly cleaner version of Rakesh's answer

```
frequency_key = 'Freq'
category_key = 'Category'
freq,category = zip(*[[(i),(j)] for i,j in zip(dict1.get(frequency_key),dict1.get(category_key)) if i!=0])
{category_key:list(category),frequency_key:list(freq)}
```

Output

```
{'Category': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], 'Freq': [71984.0, 8129.0, 3140.0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1 = {
    'Category': ['item1','item2','item3','item4'],
    'Freq': [71984.0, 8129.0, 3140.0, 0.0]
}

indices_to_delete = []
for i, e in enumerate(dict1['Freq']):
    if e == 0:
        indices_to_delete.append(i)

dict2 = {
    key: [
        v
        for i, v in enumerate(dict1[key])
        if i not in indices_to_delete
    ]
    for key in dict1.keys()
}

dict2
```

returns:

`{'Category': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], 'Freq': [71984.0, 8129.0, 3140.0]}`